# How to ingest messages from and publish messages to Solace using Apache Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, solace

My goal is to process messages from Solace and write the results back to Solace using a streaming Apache Beam pipeline on Dataflow.

What is the recommended way to integrate Solace with Beam?

Using the [MqttIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.7.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mqtt/MqttIO.html%22MqttIO%22) is one of the option. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware if there is a connector already done for Solace and Apache Beam but I think maybe extending the streamConnector of Apache Beam using the Solace Java APIs.

There are some good samples here:

https://docs.solace.com/APIs.htm